# React : How to track users statistics

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I'm using `React` as frontend and `Laravel` as backend for a mini-project.

So far each user will have content and links in his profil.

**I want to track and display for the users how many times their links were clicked and from which countries etc...**

Should I use a **Laravel package** to handle the analytics and display it with **React**? Or use **Google Analytics** for it.

If so, how can I display to each user his own statistics using **Google Analytics** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some sites giving you the comparison of [Larvel vs Google Analytics](https://www.g2.com/compare/google-analytics-vs-laravel) and [Larvel vs Google Tag Manager](https://www.g2.com/compare/laravel-vs-google-tag-manager)

Both have very similar offerings Google does not have much support Larvel does but Google community reach and thus community support is better.

Given that you are using Larvel as the backend it may make sense to use Larvel for analytics. Here is the link to [Larvel-Analytics github page](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics). The slight advantage is Larvel uses Google Analytics API and then on top of it they have layered their own visualization and metrics deck making it easier for users.

I bet you there will be others who would refer Google Analytics. In the end, both have similar offerings. Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know Laravel-Analytics! I may check it as you said because I'm using Laravel so it makes sense.

Comment: @AlyaKra Glad you found it helpful. Here is the link to the official docs https://freek.dev/498-laravel-analytics-v2-has-been-released. Would be awesome if you could please accept my answer then I get some points :D